# Is XSS possible in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion

I noticed that a question here seemed to be running the `<script>` tags inserted into the title. Does this still work?

The question in question: [how can i load <script>'s into an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935398/how-can-i-load-scripts-into-an-iframe)

Screenshot as of writing:

[image: screenshot of the page breaking]

The title has a `<script>` tag that seems to get executed with an "unexcepted token" error.

Comment: Apparently it is. Which is super annoying

Comment: hahah yeah it works, someone contact the admins before someone does something malicious (like a session id stealer, stealing an admin's cookie session or something)

Comment: I can also see a hello world on the home page of stack overflow, I will wait for this to get looked out before accessing the website again

Comment: @yivi same problem but different question, not a duplicate, and this is *SEVERE*, people can hack other people's browser sessions with this, someone should contact the admins asap!

Comment: **This should have been reported privately, not by inserting an `alert` on the question list of SO.** It's also appalling that SO fails to sanitize question titles. That's web 101 FFS.

Comment: Ouch, time to close the site and wait for an update on twitter, as of now it's dangerous to load any page with a question title...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Kinda hard to privately report something that's blatantly obvious as soon as you navigate to the site...

Comment: @Nick - It's easy: Having discovered it, you mod flag any question and report it. Or email, call, etc. - https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact If it's not fixed in a couple of days, *then* you go public.

Comment: @Nick This question is the what's causing the homepage alert (It had script injection in the title as an example)

Comment: Well, that explains why I kept getting "Hello World" notifications...

Comment: @DBS Just because this is the question that had the injection doesn't mean the vulnerability itself wasn't clear, the issue got at least 5 reports across at least 2 metas within minutes. What I meant was there's no _reason_ to privately report if the issue is already widely known. Don't forget only 0.05% of users use meta

Comment: @Nick - Ah, didn't know it had been widely reported already. But that raises the question: Why raise the profile by pwning the SO question list **also**?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, this was the 4th report on MSO, there was another on MSE potentially more on other sites ^^, appreciate that wasn't immediately clear

Comment: I can't reproduce this

Comment: @Dharman Has been fixed already, so it cannot be reproduced anymore :/

Comment: A self/auto-upvoting question would have been a more elegant proof of the XSS vulnerability than a disruptive `alert` =P

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How do you know the reaction time when you use "Contact us" isn't the usual few months?

Comment: @Scratte - *"If it's not fixed in a couple of days,* then *you go public."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not justifying the action of OP, but I think "a couple of days" could allow real malicious attack.

Comment: @LearningMathematics - Hence the desire to avoid publicizing it by reporting it privately. But yeah, maybe if you didn't get a mod reply in an hour or two (rather than a day or two) would be better. The point is: Give them a chance to fix it **before** you tell all and sundry that they can inject code in hundreds of thousands of people's browser sessions. And sure enough, btw, someone did try to take advantage of it.

Comment: Warning others that SO is risky at the moment is more useful than keeping them uninformed and thus vulnerable while hoping no "bad guy" also notices that bug and misuses it. Reporting it publicly also informs those ill-mannered people, yes, but at least a lot more users know about this issue and they can take precautions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - highly doubt the ones who tried to take advantage of the vulnerability tried that because of the report. This is basically a braindead vulnerability and, given how many of us there are, someone's definitely trying something like this as we speak. It would be another matter if the vulnerability was found in an obscure feature or required substantial skill to take advantage of - then private reporting would be a preferred way. I, for once, was about to go gleefully surf the main site when I noticed that MSO wants to greet me with an alert. I think OP did the right thing here.